# Mocking a method within tested class

Tags: php, phpunit

I am using PHPUnit 4.6.4

I am having difficulty understanding on how I can mock a method within tested class, i had a look at some other examples online but non seem to work.

I have a following function in the Auth class

```
    public function check_that_user_is_admin() {
        if ($this->get_user_role() !== '1') {
            // only admin allowed to perform this action
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
```

'get_user_role' checks active session to see what user level current user has and returns it's value.

This is a test for the function above

```
    public function testAuth() {
            $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Auth')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock(array('get_user_role'));
            $mock->expects($this->once())->method('get_user_role')->with($this->returnValue(1));

            $this->assertTrue($mock->check_that_user_is_admin());
    }
```

Everytime I run the test I receive: 
'Failed asserting that null is true.'

Answer (score 0):

I happen to find an answer...

```
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Auth')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(array('get_user_role'))
        ->getMock();

    $mock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('get_user_role')
        ->willReturn("2");

    $this->assertFalse($mock->check_that_user_is_admin());
```